# Как вернуть изображение по ссылке если оно находится вне каталога сайта?

Tags: php

Следующий код возвращает случайное фото из каталога:

```
$http_host = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST');
$request_uri = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI');
$request_uri = substr($request_uri, 0, strpos($request_uri, '/', 1) + 1);
$user_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'user_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$srand = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'srand', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

if( $user_id && $srand ){
    $DirPath = 'D:/Photo/'.$user_id.'/';
    $Photos = (array)glob($DirPath.'*.jpg');

    srand($srand);
    $Photo = $Photos[array_rand($Photos)];
    if(!$Photo ) $Photo = 'DefaultPhoto.jpg';
    header('Location: http://'.$http_host.$request_uri.$Photo);
}
```

Когда `$DirPath` был относительным и находился в каталоге сайта, всё работало. Когда архив был перенесен на отдельный диск, фотографии перестали возвращаться по ссылке. `var_dump` показывает корректный путь к файлу.

**Как реализовать возврат по ссылке если файлы на другом диске?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, выучить, как "Отче наш", [чем отличаются файлы на диске от HTTP ресурсов](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/paths). Чтобы в принципе не возникало вопросов, "а почему веб-сервер не показывает белиберду типа `http://example.com/path/D:/Photo/34465656/kartinka.jepege`?"

Во-вторых, или настроить отдельный веб-сервер для картинок (и отдавать в локейшен **корректный** URL картинки), либо использовать readfile(), что скажется на производительности, но это, как я понимаю, на данный момент проблемой не является.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Сейчас пробую `header('Content-type: image/jpg');  return file_get_contents($Photo);` - браузер пишет, что изображение не может быть показано так как содержит ошибки, хотя если этот контент перед отправкой в отладочных целях сохранить на диске, там изображение нормальное. Это с чем может быть связано?

Comment: какой эффект вы ожидаете от строчки `return file_get_contents($Photo);`? что она, по-вашему, должна делать? И где в моем ответе написано про file_get_contents?

Comment: Да, в спешке глупость написал - `return` вместо `echo`. Спасибо